# Advice on saving rubber plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, tree-care

So here is our rubber plant, it is quite large and we have recently determined that  it is suffering from overwatering. It has been losing leaves daily and now only has 2 on the main trunk and 2 (probably only 1 healthy one) on very small branches. Our current plan is to cut off the healthy branch and attempt to root it. Then we will try to replace the wet dirt with new, dry dirt and try to trim the roots as best as we can. Does anyone else have advice? Do you guys think it will make it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two small growths near the bottom in your second photo. Your idea to try and root the top growth might work, so you should try to do this with the growth that is up near the ceiling. The plant itself is congested in the pot with the other plants, and probably would also benefit from a location with more light. I can only offer the following suggestions.

1. Cut off the main trunk above the two small growths visible in the photo, then repot the main (rooted) plant in fresh potting soil. If you notice any dead roots you should remove them, but be careful not to damage any living roots.
2. Water the plant carefully, once repotted, and only when it is dry to the touch.
3. Place the repotted rubber tree in a location that receives more indirect light to stimulate growth (i.e. maybe a "partially" sunny bright location).

Hopefully, the small existing growths will strengthen, and maybe some additional new growth will be initiated from the trunk.